# scraping hidden input without IE

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, winhttp

I'm back cause  new problem.
i used vba with Excel for an enterprise intranet web page.
So the IT staff has changed  something and my old code doesen't works.
I'm using winhttp, vba excel , the url is a secured https
I need to get all the hidden input below

```
<TD class=campoSmall align=center><A class=campo 
                href="javascript:show_cartella('00720060018189241');"><INPUT 
                type=hidden value=00720060018189241 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].idCartella>00720060018189241 
                </A></TD>
              <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden value=2002 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].annoImposta>2002 </TD>
              <TD class=campoSmallImporto><INPUT type=hidden value=54,07 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].caricoRuoloEuro>54,07 </TD>
              <TD class=campoSmallImporto><INPUT type=hidden 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].importoResiduoEuro> </TD>
              <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].eventi> </TD>
              <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
                name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].asterisco> </TD><INPUT 
              type=hidden value=1 
              name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].tipoAnagrafica> <INPUT 
              type=hidden value=2006 name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].annoRuolo> 
            </TR></TBODY
```

but something is wrong..i think it is a javascript problem because i can scrape the hidden in the other tags.
thi is code page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(1351)https://SITOWEB/ecportal/analisi_esiti_contabili/elenco_dati_contabili.do -->
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<TITLE>Esiti contabili - Analisi degli Esiti Contabili</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript 
src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/script.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ruoli.css"><NOSCRIPT></NOSCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

    var primavolta = true;

    function print() {      
        document.forms[0].service.value = "PRINT";
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

    function mostraPartiteDebitore() {
        document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value = 'D';
        document.forms[0].service   .value = "ELENCO_PARTITE";
        document.forms[0].submit(); 
    }

    function nascondiPartiteDebitore() {
        document.getElementById('plusIcon') .style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('minusIcon').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('pd')       .style.display = 'none';
        document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value = '';
    }

    function mostraDestinatarioNotifica() {
        document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value = 'N';
        document.forms[0].service   .value = "ELENCO_PARTITE";
        document.forms[0].submit(); 
    }

    function nascondiDestinatarioNotifica() {
        document.getElementById('plusIcon2') .style.display = '';
        document.getElementById('minusIcon2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('dn')        .style.display = 'none';
        document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value = '';
    }

    function show_partita(
            codiceFiscale,
            tipoAnagrafica,
            codiceUfficio,
            descrUfficio,
            codiceTipoModello,
            idPartita,
            annoImposta,
            annoRuolo) {

        document.forms[0].service                     .value = "SHOW_PARTITA";
        document.forms[0].codiceFiscale               .value = codiceFiscale;
        document.forms[0].tipoAnagraficaSelezionato   .value = tipoAnagrafica;
        document.forms[0].codiceUfficioSelezionato    .value = codiceUfficio;
        document.forms[0].descrUfficioSelezionato     .value = descrUfficio;
        document.forms[0].codiceTipoModelloSelezionato.value = codiceTipoModello;
        document.forms[0].idPartitaSelezionato        .value = idPartita;
        document.forms[0].annoImpostaSelezionato      .value = annoImposta;
        document.forms[0].annoRuoloSelezionato        .value = annoRuolo;

        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

    function show_cartella(idCartella) {
        document.forms[0].service.value = "SHOW_CARTELLA";
        document.forms[0].idCartellaSelezionato.value = idCartella;     
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

    function openPdf(url, nome) {
        window.open(url, nome);
    }   

    function mostraElenchi() {
        if (document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value == 'D') {

            document.getElementById('plusIcon') .style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('minusIcon').style.display = '';
            if (!document.forms[0].partiteDestNotificaEmpty.value) nascondiDestinatarioNotifica() ;

        } else if(document.forms[0].tipoElenco.value == 'N') {

            document.getElementById('plusIcon2') .style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('minusIcon2').style.display = '';   
            if (!document.forms[0].partiteDebitoreEmpty.value) nascondiPartiteDebitore();
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>

<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.19431"></HEAD>
<BODY onload=mostraElenchi()>
<FORM method=post name=elencoDatiContabiliForm 
action=/ecportal/analisi_esiti_contabili/elenco_dati_contabili.do><INPUT 
type=hidden name=service> <INPUT type=hidden value=EUR name=tipoValutaElenco> 
<INPUT type=hidden value="ENT - ENTRATE" name=tipologiaRuolo.descrizioneEstesa> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=tipoAnagraficaSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=codiceUfficioSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden name=descrUfficioSelezionato> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=codiceTipoModelloSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=idPartitaSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden name=annoImpostaSelezionato> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=annoRuoloSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=idCartellaSelezionato> <INPUT type=hidden value=true 
name=partiteDebitoreEmpty> <INPUT type=hidden value=true 
name=partiteDestNotificaEmpty> <INPUT type=hidden value=D name=tipoElenco> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=tipoElencoProvenienza> 
<!-- per importi rilevanti--><INPUT type=hidden name=dataConsegnaDa> <INPUT 
type=hidden name=dataConsegnaAl> <INPUT type=hidden name=importoPartitaDa> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=importoPartitaAl> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=tipoAttoRicerca> <INPUT type=hidden name=direzioneRegionale> <INPUT 
type=hidden name=ufficioImpRil> <INPUT type=hidden name=raggruppamentoAtto> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=chkMax500> <INPUT type=hidden name=tipoUfficio> <INPUT 
type=hidden name=direzione7> <INPUT type=hidden name=direzione9> <INPUT 
type=hidden name=tipoUfficio> <INPUT type=hidden value=ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT 
name=codiceFiscale> <INPUT type=hidden name=cfCollegato> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=tipoRuolo> <INPUT type=hidden name=elenco> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=paginaAttualeEl> <INPUT type=hidden name=totalePagineEl> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=paginaAttualeDett> <INPUT type=hidden name=totalePagineDett> <INPUT 
type=hidden name=ufficioDettaglio> <INPUT type=hidden name=tipoAttoDettaglio> 
<INPUT type=hidden name=ufficioDettaglio> <INPUT type=hidden 
name=dataConsegnaDettaglio> <INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=totDeb> <INPUT 
type=hidden value=0 name=totNot> <INPUT type=hidden name=ufficioLoggato> 
<DIV align=center>
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>
    document.forms[0].tipoElencoProvenienza.value = "D";
  </SCRIPT>

<TABLE height=141 width=750 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD height=71 width=163>
      <DIV align=left><IMG border=0 alt="menu principale" 
      src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_esiticontabili_ruoli.gif" 
      width=260 height=55></DIV></TD>
    <TD vAlign=bottom width=378 align=right><A 
      href="javascript:logout();"><IMG border=0 alt=logout 
      src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_ruoli_logout.gif"> 
      </A></TD>
    <TD width=189>
      <DIV align=center><IMG alt="logo SITOSITO" 
      src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/LogoAgenzia.jpg" 
      width=200 height=47></DIV></TD></TR>
  <TR bgColor=#336699>
    <TD height=20 colSpan=3>
      <DIV align=left><SPAN class=sottotitolo>Il portale dell'agenzia per gli 
      esiti contabili </SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD height=20 
    background=Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_linearuoli.png 
    colSpan=4>
      <DIV align=left>
      <TABLE width="100%">
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD class=etichetta width="50%">Analisi degli esiti contabili</TD>
          <TD class=campo width="50%" align=right><A class=guidapdf 
            href='javascript:openPdf("/ecportal/analisi_esiti_contabili/pdfResources/GuidaAnalisiEsitiContabili.pdf","GUIDA_APPLICAZIONE");'><SPAN>GUIDA&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><INPUT 
type=hidden 
value="RUOLIANALISI.RUOLIANALISIHOME/HOME > RUOLIANALISI.RIASSUNTOCONTABILE/Riassunto contabile > RUOLIANALISI.ELENCODATICONTABILI/Elenco dati contabili" 
name=history> 
<TABLE class=bordo height=20 width=746>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=etichetta><A class=etichetta 
      href="javascript:navbar('RUOLIANALISI.RUOLIANALISIHOME')">HOME</A> &gt; <A 
      class=etichetta 
      href="javascript:navbar('RUOLIANALISI.RIASSUNTOCONTABILE')">Riassunto 
      contabile</A> &gt; Elenco dati contabili </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

    function highline(navservice) {
        pattern = "(" + navservice + "\/)";
        reHighline = new RegExp(pattern);
        reClear = /#/;
        document.forms[0].history.value = document.forms[0].history.value.replace(reClear, "");
        document.forms[0].history.value = document.forms[0].history.value.replace(reHighline, "#$1");
    }

    function navbar(navservice) {
        highline(navservice);
        document.forms[0].service.value = "NAVBAR";
        document.forms[0].submit();
        disabilitaPagina();
    }
</SCRIPT>

<TABLE width=750 border=0>
  <TBODY></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE height=250 width=750 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD height=240 vAlign=top width=144 align=center>
      <DIV align=left></DIV>
      <TABLE width=156 align=left border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR bgColor=#cccccc>
          <TD class=menuLv1Disabled vAlign=top>
            <DIV align=left><SPAN class=menuLv1Disabled>PARTITE</SPAN> 
        </DIV></TD></TR>
        <TR bgColor=#cccccc>
          <TD class=menuLv1Fired vAlign=top>
            <DIV align=left><SPAN class=menuLv1Fired>RIASSUNTO CONTABILE</SPAN> 
            </DIV></TD></TR>
        <TR bgColor=#cccccc>
          <TD class=menuLv1Disabled vAlign=top>
            <DIV align=left><SPAN class=menuLv1Disabled>IMPORTI RILEVANTI</SPAN> 
            </DIV></TD></TR>
        <TR bgColor=#cccccc>
          <TD class=menuLv1Disabled vAlign=top>
            <DIV align=left><SPAN class=menuLv1Disabled>DATI CONSEGNE</SPAN> 
            </DIV></TD></TR>
        <TR bgColor=#cccccc>
          <TD class=menuLv1Disabled vAlign=top>
            <DIV align=left><SPAN class=menuLv1Disabled>DISCARICO 
            INESIGIBILITA'</SPAN> </DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <P align=left>&nbsp;</P>
      <P align=left>&nbsp;</P>
      <P align=left>&nbsp;</P>
      <P align=left>&nbsp;</P></TD>
    <TD vAlign=top width=585>
      <TABLE class=bordo width=580>
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=intestazione>
          <TD>
            <DIV align=center>Riassunto contabile</DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <TABLE width=580 border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD colSpan=2>
            <DIV class=etichetta>Codice fiscale</DIV>
            <DIV class=campo><INPUT type=hidden value=ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT 
            name=codiceFiscale>ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT</DIV></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD colSpan=5>
            <DIV class=etichetta>Cognome nome/Denominazione</DIV>
            <DIV class=campo><INPUT type=hidden 
            value="PIPPO CARLO                                  " 
            name=cognomeDenominaz>PIPPO CARLO 
      </DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR>
      <TABLE width=580 border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD align=center><LABEL class=etichetta>Tipologia ruolo:</LABEL> 
            <LABEL class=campo><INPUT type=hidden value=ENTRATE 
            name=tipologiaRuolo.descrizione>ENTRATE</LABEL> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <TABLE width=580 border=0><!--tr> 
          <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr-->
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=intestazioneTabella>
          <TD align=center>Numero partite</TD>
          <TD align=center>Debito totale</TD>
          <TD align=center>Importo sgravato</TD>
          <TD align=center>Importo sospeso</TD>
          <TD align=center>Importo riscosso</TD>
          <TD align=center>Importo residuo</TD></TR>
        <TR class=tabella>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden value=1 
            name=numeroPartite>1</TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            value=54,07 name=debitoTotale>54,07</TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=importoSgravato></TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=importoSospeso></TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            value=54,07 name=importoRiscosso>54,07</TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=importoResiduo></TD></TR><INPUT type=hidden name=importoCondono> 
        </TBODY></TABLE><BR>
      <TABLE width=585 border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR id=plusIcon>
          <TH width=30><A href="javascript:mostraPartiteDebitore();"><IMG 
            border=0 
            src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_ruoli_plus.gif"></A> 
          </TH>
          <TH align=left><SPAN class=collegamento>Elenco partite per cui il 
            soggetto è debitore</SPAN> </TH></TR>
        <TR id=minusIcon style="DISPLAY: none">
          <TH width=30><A href="javascript:nascondiPartiteDebitore();"><IMG 
            border=0 
            src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_ruoli_minus.gif"></A> 
          </TH>
          <TH align=left><SPAN class=collegamento>Elenco partite per cui il 
            soggetto è debitore</SPAN> </TH></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <DIV id=pd>
      <SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

</SCRIPT>

      <TABLE class=bordo width=580>
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=intestazione>
          <TD>
            <DIV align=center>Elenco partite per cui il soggetto è 
          debitore</DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <DIV class=tabellaElencoPartite style="HEIGHT: 70px">
      <TABLE width=800 border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=intestazioneTabellaSmall>
          <TD align=center>Data consegna</TD>
          <TD align=center>Uff.</TD>
          <TD align=center>Tipo Mod.</TD>
          <TD align=center>Tipo sogg.</TD>
          <TD align=center>Id.partita</TD>
          <TD align=center>Id.cartella</TD>
          <TD align=center>Anno imp.</TD>
          <TD align=center>Carico a ruolo</TD>
          <TD align=center>Importo residuo</TD>
          <TD align=center>Eventi</TD>
          <TD align=center>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
        <TR class=tabella>
          **<TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            value=25-11-2006 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].dataConsegna>25-11-2006 </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden value=R5D 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].ufficio.descrizione>R5D <INPUT 
            type=hidden value=U 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].ufficio.codice> </TD>
          <TD title="TASSAZIONE SEPARATA" class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT 
            type=hidden value=TS 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].tipoModello.codice>TS <INPUT 
            type=hidden value="TASSAZIONE SEPARATA" 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].tipoModello.descrizione> </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            value="INTESTATARIO             " 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].tipoSoggetto>INTESTATARIO </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><A class=campo 
            href="javascript:show_partita('ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT','1','U','R5D','TS','ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT/A02          ','2002','2006');"><INPUT 
            type=hidden value="ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT/A02          " 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].idPartita>ABCDEFXXGXXGYYYT/A02 
            </A></TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><A class=campo 
            href="javascript:show_cartella('00720060018189241');"><INPUT 
            type=hidden value=00720060018189241 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].idCartella>00720060018189241 
            </A></TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden value=2002 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].annoImposta>2002 </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto><INPUT type=hidden value=54,07 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].caricoRuoloEuro>54,07 </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmallImporto><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].importoResiduoEuro> </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].eventi> </TD>
          <TD class=campoSmall align=center><INPUT type=hidden 
            name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].asterisco> </TD><INPUT 
          type=hidden value=1 
          name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].tipoAnagrafica> <INPUT 
          type=hidden value=2006 name=elencoPartiteDebitoreIndexed[0].annoRuolo> 
        </TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV><!-- Paginazione -->**
      <TABLE align=center>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>
            <DIV align=center>
            <SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>

    function showPage(pag) {
        document.forms[0].service.value = "ELENCO_PARTITE";
        document.forms[0].numeroPagSelElencoDatiContabili.value = pag;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }   

    function nuovaPagina(){
        document.forms[0].service.value = "NEW_PAGE";
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

</SCRIPT>
            <INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=numeroPagSelElencoDatiContabili> 
            <INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=paginaAttualeElencoDatiContabili> 
            <INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=totalePagineElencoDatiContabili> 
            <TABLE id=tabellaPaginazione class=paginazione width=575 
            align=center border=0>
              <TBODY>
              <TR class=intestazioneTabella>
                <TD align=center>Pagina 1&nbsp;/&nbsp;1 </TD></TR>
              <TR class=etichetta>
                <TD align=center>1 
      </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR></DIV>
      <TABLE width=585 border=0>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TH width=30><IMG border=0 
            src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_ruoli_quadro.gif"> 
          </TH>
          <TH align=left><SPAN class=collegamento>Elenco partite per cui il 
            soggetto è destinatario di notifica</SPAN> </TH></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR>
      <TABLE width=580 align=center>
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=etichetta>
          <TD colSpan=6 align=left><SPAN>(*) Partita con versamento superiore 
            al dovuto</SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <TABLE width=580 align=center>
        <TBODY>
        <TR class=etichetta>
          <TD colSpan=6 align=center><BR><BR><SPAN>stampa elenco (in formato 
            excel) o seleziona partita da interrogare</SPAN> </TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD colSpan=11 align=center><BR>
            <DIV align=center><A href="javascript:print();"><IMG border=0 
            alt=stampa 
            src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/ec_tasto_ruoli_stampa.gif" 
            width=128 
height=30></A></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width=750 border=0>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TH width=255 scope=col>&nbsp;</TH>
    <TH width=405 scope=col>
      <DIV align=right><SPAN class=etichetta>a cura di</SPAN></DIV></TH>
    <TH width=106 scope=col>
      <DIV align=center><IMG alt="logo SSSSS" 
      src="Esiti%20contabili%20-%20Analisi%20degli%20Esiti%20Contabili_do_file/LogoSSSSS.png" 
      width=91 height=40></DIV></TH></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<P>&nbsp;</P></DIV></FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: So is the top what you were expecting but the bottom is what you are getting?